# Slow SSRS report when the Datasource is on Azure

Tags: reporting-services, azure-sql-database

I have an existing SSRS instance that has been in place for a few years.  The data DB is on the same box and the report always loads very quickly.

I'm moving the data DB out to Azure and the rendering time has skyrocketed.  The dataset is a stored procedure that executes in less than a second in SSMS.  This report also loads instantly in BIDS.  Once it's on the SSRS server, it takes 30 seconds.

Data on Azure:

```
    <EstimatedMemoryUsageKB>
    <Pagination>4</Pagination>
    <Processing>13</Processing>
  </EstimatedMemoryUsageKB>
  <DataExtension>
    <SQLAZURE>1</SQLAZURE>
  </DataExtension>
  <Connections>
    <Connection>
      <ConnectionOpenTime>1</ConnectionOpenTime>
      <DataSets>
        <DataSet>
          <Name>ProjectTasks</Name>
          <RowsRead>9</RowsRead>
          <TotalTimeDataRetrieval>30034</TotalTimeDataRetrieval>
          <QueryPrepareAndExecutionTime>0</QueryPrepareAndExecutionTime>
          <ExecuteReaderTime>22</ExecuteReaderTime>
          <DataReaderMappingTime>0</DataReaderMappingTime>
          <DisposeDataReaderTime>0</DisposeDataReaderTime>
```

Data on the same server as SSRS:

```
  <EstimatedMemoryUsageKB>
    <Pagination>4</Pagination>
    <Processing>12</Processing>
  </EstimatedMemoryUsageKB>
  <DataExtension>
    <SQL>1</SQL>
  </DataExtension>
  <Connections>
    <Connection>
      <ConnectionOpenTime>1</ConnectionOpenTime>
      <DataSets>
        <DataSet>
          <Name>ProjectTasks</Name>
          <RowsRead>8</RowsRead>
          <TotalTimeDataRetrieval>1</TotalTimeDataRetrieval>
          <QueryPrepareAndExecutionTime>0</QueryPrepareAndExecutionTime>
          <ExecuteReaderTime>1</ExecuteReaderTime>
          <DataReaderMappingTime>0</DataReaderMappingTime>
          <DisposeDataReaderTime>0</DisposeDataReaderTime>
        </DataSet>
```

This doesn't happen to ALL of my reports where the data is on Azure, just some.  I've already tried modifying my stored procedure WITH RECOMPILE, OPTION OPTIMIZE, and assigning the SP's parameter to an inner variable.  Nothing changes the TotalTimeDataRetrieval.

My Azure DB is S2 Standard (50 DTUs).  I haven't seen it go above 1 or 2% all day.
[image]

Comment: Are you working within an hybrid environment?, like your SSRS runs locally and the database is in the Azure Cloud?

Comment: SSRS is on a dedicated server within our intranet.  Yes, the database is on Azure SQL

Comment: Mmmm...I think that maybe the problem should be related to bandwidth issues

Comment: Wouldn't those also show up in SSMS or BIDS from my local machine?

Comment: There is a difference when you have a local intranet environment, versus accessing a layer from a remote internet resource(the typical Internet Speed Vs. LAN Speed tradeoff)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear.  When I say SSMS/BIDS, I'm accessing the Azure database.  I also just tested from SSMS on the SSRS server.

Comment: Your current scenario: when you run it from your SSMS/BIDS client, and the speed look like the same, but when you run it as an SSRS report(web application) it takes a lot of time to render, right?

Comment: Correct.  30 seconds seems pretty insane for 9 rows when the query is milliseconds in any other scenario.

Comment: Press F12 on your web browser...check the network tab and reload the page...check which is taking so long to render...also if you want, take an screenshot and add it to your question

Comment: Added.  I'm not sure that it helps much because it just shows the 30s for the report.

Comment: Are you adding those query hints aimlessly or are you actually getting bad plans? Is there a difference in the plan when you change the data source?

Comment: It's hard to say because I can't see the plans when SSRS is running against Azure.  I tested those query hints one at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if something was cached incorrectly or what the actual cause was but I noticed my problem reports all had a stored procedure as the query type for the Dataset.  I changed it to Text and the problem went away.  I changed it back to the stored procedure and it was still fixed.

My subreport in the question went from 30s to 450ms.  The overall report went from 2.5 minutes to 4 seconds.